# SPServices radiobutton click event

Tags: spservices

I have 3 lists

quiz

Questions

answers

Quiz - list columns

Title

Description

Number of Questions

Questions

Quiz-title (from the above list) tells which questions belong to which quiz

Question

Question Number

AnswerA

AnswerB

AnswerC

AnswerD

Correct Answer

Answer- list

quizname

Question

username

useranswer

Correct answer

the first page to load is the quiz page (nothing but the quiz list)

user clicks on a particular quiz and is directed to the questions page (the above page)

it loads relevant questions and and answera, answerb, answerc,answerd

each question has 4 radio buttons and the user can check 1 radio button

I want to capture the quiz name , question , question number , useranswer  and post that in the answers

list

how do i capture the useranswer (which is one of the radiobuttons) per question

once the user hits submit button , he is redirected to the results page with a pass/fail (calculated from

answers list)

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() { 

GetQuestions();


$("#SubmitAnswers").click(function() {

     alert(" inside submit");
     //get key value pairs of question number and answer for that question
     //insert key value pair into a another list 

  }); 
 });


function GetQuestions()
{

    var list = "Questions";
    var queryStringVals = $().SPServices.SPGetQueryString();
    var quizID = queryStringVals["varname"];

    var fieldsToRead =     "<ViewFields>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='Description' />" +
                           "</ViewFields>";

    var query = "<Query>" +
                    "<Where>" +
                     "<Eq>" + 
                            "<FieldRef Name='Quiz' /><Value Type='Text'>" + quizID + "</Value>" +
                        "</Eq>" +


                        "<Neq>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Number'>0</Value>" + 
                        "</Neq>" +
                    "</Where>" +
                    "<OrderBy>" + 
                        "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>" +
                    "</OrderBy>" +
                "</Query>";


                 var method = "GetListItems";                 
                var webURL =  $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() ;                     
                var list = "Questions";                      
                var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>"+"<FieldRef Name='Name' />" +"</ViewFields>";


                $().SPServices({
                    operation: method,
                    async: false, 
                    webURL: webURL,
                    listName: list,
                    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",
                    CAMLQuery: query,                                                                                     
                    completefunc: function (xData, Status)
                     {
                         $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() 
                         {
                              var ID = $(this).attr("ows_ID");
                              var title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
                              var questionNumber = $(this).attr("ows_QuestionNumber");
                              var question = $(this).attr("ows_Question");
                              var answera =  $(this).attr("ows_AnswerA");
                              var answerb = $(this).attr("ows_AnswerB");
                              var answerc = $(this).attr("ows_AnswerC");
                              var answerd = $(this).attr("ows_AnswerD");

                               $("#myDataTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
                               "<td align='left'>Question Number <span class='QuestionNumber'>  "+ questionNumber+"</td></tr><tr>" + 
                               "<td align='left'> <span class='Question'>  "+ question+"</td></tr><tr>" + 


                               "<td align='left'>"+ answera+"</td></tr><tr>" + 
                               "<td align='left'>"+ answerb+"</td></tr><tr>" + 
                               "<td align='left'>"+ answerc+"</td></tr><tr>" + 
                               "<td align='left'>"+ answerd+"</td></tr><tr>" + 


                                "<form name='answers' class='answers' id='answers'>" + 
                               "<td align='left'><input type='radio' name='rbanswer' value='a'>a</td></tr><tr>" + 
                                "<td align='left'><input type='radio' name='rbanswer' value='b'>b</td></tr><tr>" +
                               "<td align='left'><input type='radio' name='rbanswer' value='c'>c</td></tr><tr>" + 
                                "<td align='left'><input type='radio' name='rbanswer' value='d'>d</td></tr><tr>" +
                                "<td align='left'></td></tr><tr>" +
                                "<td align='left'></td>" +                                  

                               "</tr><br><p>");
                           });
                   }
       });



}
```

**Quiz**

```
<input name="SubmitAnswers" id="SubmitAnswers" type="button" value="Submit" style="height: 21px; width: 50px">
```

Comment: From the looks of it, the script you posted isn't all there. I'd suggest you clean it up and only post the bit you are having an issue with.

Comment: Ok I tried to format is as much as I can